# How to call HTML files from json to load them in a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am working on a project which displays HTML content from a json file. Based on the id, the content of the page is displayed.

It is tedious to write HTML content inside json, how can I avoid this and maintain separate HTMl files and call them based on the id's in the json file

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "1st page",
  "type": "Info",
  "content": [
        "<h2>Heading</h2>"
      ],
  "active": false
}
```

The content loads in the template :-

```
<h1>Template 1</h1> 
{{{content}}}
```

Comment: how you are writing html contents?? can you provide the same??

Comment: <h1>Template 1</h1>
{{{content}}}

Comment: I meant what type of structure you wanna create with `json`? `<table>`or `<div>` or any other?

Comment: div, basically I want to call any HTML file as the design for each page is different...

Comment: Well, **[this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-handlebars--net-27761)** might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load html files in a element using jquery:

```
$( "div" ).load( "test.html" );
```

Comment: try this instead :` $('#some_id').append($( "div" ).load( "test.html" ));`

Comment: the load worked with a slight tweak to the code - $(\"#appendToThis\").load(\"test.html#posts\");

Comment: this also helped - https://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-but-append-data-instead-of-replace

Answer (score 1):

Two thing you could do:

1. You can use a template engine like `handlebars` and use the json data to inject values inside a template and render it.
2. Or, you could build html on the fly using the json and render it.

My vote would be to use a template engine if you are generating way too much html.

Comment: this is how the content loads - <h1>Template 1</h1> {{{content}}}

Comment: Will be a bit of a long answer, look this up. http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2013/10/using-handlebar-template-for-json-response.html/
If my solution solves your problem, accept it, may be :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use .load().
 Please check it out here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Instead of passing html content in content of your json, Just pass the html file name and use .load to load that particular file

Answer (score 0):

Actually there many library to do that templating js like

**Choose your Best option**

dustJS (created by linkedin)

http://jsfiddle.net/jaltez/e8hmc/

HandlebarsJS (simple code see jsfiddle link)

```
var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = { 
    users: [ { 
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry", 
            lastName: "Finch"
        },
        jobTitle: "Front End Technical Lead",
        twitter: "gazraa" 
    }, {
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry", 
            lastName: "Finch"
        }, 
        jobTitle: "Photographer",
        twitter: "photobasics"
    }, {
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry", 
            lastName: "Finch"
        }, 
        jobTitle: "LEGO Geek",
        twitter: "minifigures"
    } ]
}; 

Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(person) {
  return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
});

$('body').append(template(data));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aybalasubramanian/N2b5M/1/

and

independent js frameworks

ANGULARJS

http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pj5br/

BackboneJS with combination with Handlebarjs

http://jsfiddle.net/cmckeachie/tM87J/light/